# How to create a new column in my df which is the numbers of days between two dates (with different data type)

Tags: python-3.x, python-datetime

I have a dataframe that contains two columns. First column is the as_of_date which data type is object. Second column is the sales_date which data type is datetime 64[ns], see below.

```
as_of_date    sales_date
2021-06-29    2021-06-27 16:06:55
2021-06-29    2021-06-03 14:33:25

df[['as_of_date','sales_date']].dtypes
as_of_date    object
sales_date    datetime64[ns]
dtype:object
```

My goal is to create a 3rd column in my df to show the # of days between as_of_date and sales_date as below. Is there anyway to get this work?

```
as_of_date    sales_date             days
2021-06-29    2021-06-27 16:06:55    2
2021-06-29    2021-06-03 14:33:25    26
```

Comment: Did you tried any thing.

Comment: I tried several approaches but none of them works

Answer (score 2):

If the dates are `datetime` objects, you can use the `timestamp` method to retrieve the timestamp. Then what you would do is substract `as_of_date` timestamp to `sales_date` timestamp, divide it by 86400 (number of seconds in a day) and pass it through the `int` method to get an integer number.